# had been living/was living/lived

Tags: tense

He quit his job in 2000, he lived there from 2000 till 2002. Now it's 2022.

> 1 He had been living there for two years since he **quit** his job.
>
> 2 He had been living there for two years since he **had quit** his
> job.
>
> 3 He was living there for two years since he **(had) quit** his job.
>
> 4 He lived there for two years since he **(had) quit** his job.

Which options are correct?

Answer (score 2):

We only use *since* if the situation being described is ongoing. (1) and (2) are correct if they are part of a narrative about events in 2002. You could also say **since quitting his job.**

If you are making a statement from the point of view of today (2022), you have to say

> He lived there for two years after quitting his job. (*or,* after he (had) quit his job.)

Comment: Upvoted but this is simply not true "We only use since if the situation being described is ongoing." See https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/since  When since is used for talking about time, the verb in the main clause of the sentence is usually in the present perfect or past perfect tense: It hasn’t rained since the end of July.He had been composing music since he was ten years old. Sometimes the present simple or past simple is used in the main clause: It’s over twenty years since we last met

Comment: Another thing "He was ill for two days after quitting his job." I think it wrong. "He had been ill for two days..." Do u agree?

Comment: There being no rain is an ongoing situation, and presumably the composer was still writing music! _He was ill for two days after quitting his job_ is a simple statement of fact. _He had been ill..._ would need to be followed with something like _...but by the following week he was actively seeking work again_ - that is, a statement from the perspective of later events.

Comment: But you said that SINCE is only used when the action is relevant to the present. Apparently it's not always the case as the dictionary gives this example "He had been composing music since he was ten years old."  You say "and presumably the composer was still writing music!" - well maybe, but "was writing" is not relevant to the present, it's in the past. What confused me is you saying that "since" can't be used with the past while the dictionary gives a counterexample.

Comment: I said nothing about 'relevance to the present'. The composer had started to write music at the age of ten, and the author implies that, at the time they are talking about, he was still doing so. (It was an ongoing situation.)

Comment: OK. If the person is dead. "He had been composing music since he was 10". He died 100 years ago. There is not an ongoing process. What tense should be used?

Comment: _In 1890 X began to study at the Royal College of Music. He had been composing music since he was ten._ If a particular date is not mentioned and the subject is no longer alive, we would say _He began to compose music when he was ten._

Comment: OK. "He began to compose" is clear. What if I need to point out the period of time. I want to say that starting from 10 he composed music for 20 years.

Comment: "He composed music from the age of ten until his early death at 30" is one possibility.

Comment: Kate Which one is correct? FIRST - How long did Jane work at CCL? - She resigned in 2000 from LLP. She worked at CCL for 5 years after she RESIGNED from LLP. SECOND - How long did Jane work at CCL? - She resigned in 2000 from LLP. She HAD WORKED at CCL for 5 years SINCE she RESIGNED from LLP.

Comment: The first one is correct (you could also say _after resigning from LLP)_. If Jane no longer works for CCL, you wouldn't use _since_ unless you went on to mention what she did next. _Jane retired in 2005. She had been working at CCL for five years since resigning from LLP._

Comment: Is this correct? He composed music for 10 years from the age of ten.

Comment: It's correct grammatically, but it seems an unlikely thing to say, unless he gave up composing at 20 and started doing something else!

Comment: People give up things now and then

Comment: Indeed they do, but such a situation is so exceptional that it would most likely be described in some other way, for example "He began to compose at the early age of ten, but by the time he was 20 he had abandoned music for literature."